Optimizing Complex SQL LEFT JOIN with Multiple Subqueries
I have a complex SQL query that involves a LEFT JOIN with multiple subqueries and conditions. The query seems quite convoluted and I'm wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to write it. Here's the code:
LEFT JOIN ODS.YARDI_COMMAMENDMENTS ALU ON
    A.HTENANT = ALU.HTENANT AND
    A.DTSTART <= ALU.DTSTART AND
    ALU.ITYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND
    ALU.ISTATUS IN (1, 2) AND
    ALU.HMY IN (SELECT UX2.HAMENDMENT FROM ODS.YARDI_UNITXREF UX2 WHERE
        U.HMY = UX2.HUNIT AND
        ALU.HMY = UX2.HAMENDMENT) AND
    COALESCE(ALU.DTMOVEOUT, ALU.DTEND, CJ.VAR_DTDATE) = (
        SELECT MAX(ALU_DATE)
        FROM (
            SELECT COALESCE(A3.DTMOVEOUT, A3.DTEND, CJ.VAR_DTDATE) AS ALU_DATE
            FROM ODS.YARDI_COMMAMENDMENTS A3
            WHERE
                A.HTENANT = A3.HTENANT AND
                A.DTSTART <= A3.DTSTART AND
                A3.ITYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND 
                A3.ISTATUS IN (1, 2) AND
                A3.HMY IN (SELECT UX3.HAMENDMENT FROM ODS.YARDI_UNITXREF UX3 WHERE
                    U.HMY = UX3.HUNIT AND
                    A3.HMY = UX3.HAMENDMENT)
        ) ALU_SUB
    ) AND
    ALU.HMY = (SELECT 
        MAX(A4.HMY)
        FROM ODS.YARDI_COMMAMENDMENTS A4
        WHERE
            A.HTENANT = A4.HTENANT AND
            A.DTSTART <= A4.DTSTART AND
            COALESCE(ALU.DTMOVEOUT, ALU.DTEND, CJ.VAR_DTDATE) = COALESCE(A4.DTMOVEOUT, A4.DTEND, VAR_DTDATE) AND
            A4.ITYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND
            A4.ISTATUS IN (1, 2) AND
            A4.HMY IN (SELECT UX4.HAMENDMENT FROM ODS.YARDI_UNITXREF UX4 WHERE
                U.HMY = UX4.HUNIT AND
                A4.HMY = UX4.HAMENDMENT))


I have considered using Common Table Expressions (CTEs), but doing so would require rewriting a substantial amount of code since it involves referencing columns outside the CTEs.
Any feedback is appreciated I don't expect someone to provide any code, just any form of suggestion will be very helpful.

You have tagged SQL Server and Oracle. These are two different RDBMS with different syntaxes; which one are you using?

Almost certainly a more efficient way to write this. At first glance I might use a CTE to handle part of the YARDI_UNITXREF tables (as you suggested), and I might join to this CTE earlier in the query to reduce repetition of both code and data access. From there you could also use a windowing function to replace some of the MAX() subqueries. But this is complicated enough I'd want to have sample data, know more about the indexes, and an hour or two to fiddle with it... which is kind of a large scope for a Stack Overflow question.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  t.value IN (SELECT MAX(m.value)
                   FROM   table_name m
                   WHERE  t.id = m.id)

can be rewritten as:
SELECT t.*
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
) t
WHERE  rnk = 1

Where you have complicated correlated self-joins to try to find the maximum they can be rewritten in exactly the same way to use an analytic function rather than the self-join.

Hi mr MTO , can you please give one elaborate example , on how to achieve this

@KKU Please can you edit your question and provide a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data that is representative of the problem; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; a complete (but minimal) query (not just the JOINs); and the expected output for that sample data. Without the necessary detail to the question it will be impossible to provide a more relevant answer (and the question does say "I don't expect someone to provide any code").
